# Affix gets blinking when scrolling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

using Affix on my site, it works fine when the text is long, but it gets blinking when text is short. You could visit the site to have a more details about this issue: 54.255.153.55/courses/php-101/chapters/5

How could I fix it?

Comment: I do not see anything blinking. What browser do you use?

Comment: I use Chrome on Windows, it gets bliking when text on the right side is short. I updated the link.

Comment: unfortunately, I wasn't able to solve this issue. It is flickering indeed :-( I think this may be a bug in Bootstrap.